# why writing into file in binary format result in different size files?

Tags: python

I write a downloaded file into file in two ways,one is in "w" ,other is in "wb".

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url="http://quotes.money.163.com/service/lrb_000559.html"  
html=urlopen(url)
outfile=open("g:\\000559a.csv","w")
outfile.write(html.read().decode("gbk"))
outfile.close()
html=urlopen(url)
outfile=open("g:\\000559b.csv","wb")
outfile.write(html.read())
outfile.close()
```

Why the way of "wb" result in different size  files?please see attachment.
The more confused thing is that in fact g:\000559a.csv is  6976 bytes,not 6575 in the console; g:\000559b.csv is 6931,the same as 6931 in the console.
The output in the console is not the same as in file manager.

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with `w` vs `wb`.  It's your encoding.  `len(html.read().decode('gbk'))` is 6575 and `len(html.read())` is 6931.  Now, `write` is supposed to report the number of *bytes* written, not characters, so I have no idea what's going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the default (text) mode under Windows, the carriage-return character `\x0d` is stripped from output. This does not happen in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance I can see that you decoded the content into a `str` type, and the write operation under that mode return the number of unicode characters under the standard mode, rather than total number of bytes as under the binary mode.  You can verify the length of the decoded `str` by this:

```
>>> s = html.read().decode("gbk")
>>> len(s)
6575
```

It matches the number of *characters* written as reported.